# Organize Folders In Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have uploaded some music folders from my computer to my Ubuntu One storage. I want to know if there is a way to have those folders moved into another folder I created or have them sync to that folder in Ubuntu One. Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more explicit, giving an example of what your problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu One is an automatic synchronization service so anything you change in your Ubuntu one folder will after a short delay be duplicated online and on anyother systems you have connected with the same account.

Example.

I am on holiday with my laptop. I take some pictures and transfer them to my laptop putting them in my Ubuntu one folder. I have a Computer at home which is signed in to my Ubuntu one account and turned on. It will receive a copy of those files in a few minutes. At which point the files will be mirrored in three different places the laptop, online and in the computer at home. One additional feature is the ability to add folders external to the Ubuntu one folder to be synced by Ubuntu one for you. Your documents folder for example.

I hope this helps explain the feature a bit better for you.